# how to style an horizontal menu with images on top and centered text?

Tags: css, html-lists, styling, css-sprites

By taking into consideration the following image, representing the 3 states of this menu interaction:

[image: horizontal menu with 3 states]

And knowing that:

**1)** We cannot have one image for all the horizontal menu, each item, (so, each ul li a) should have their own image;

**2)**
background image positioning will be favored since it will be better regarding cross-browser issues;

**3)**
The text on those buttons (should be) text and not an image;

**What would be the best way for achieving this ?** 
I just need a kick off here.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Here's a test with no swapping images:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cq5JY/

Comment: Just a side request... Where can I get the CSS for the menu above? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/bbjYC/

Comment: Thank you. But the exact CSS/HTML for the theme. I was looking through and it looks like it is a paid menu system.

Comment: This one was custom made. No theme. ;)

Comment: Any chance of sharing it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply you've kind of spelt out your solution yourself I think.

Each item in the navigation needs 1 image with three states for the rollover and active states.  Then you would move the background image using CSS as you mentioned depending on the way you layout the images.

The thing that makes the css a bit tricky (well you'll be writing a fair amount) is the text positioning on buttons, if the text starts at lots of different y coordinates then obviously you will be writing each one of these in to the CSS.

I would setup the nav using the code similar to the below (untested) based on a separate image for each button, which has in it the regular state of the button, underneath the rollover and underneath that, the active state of the button.

```
/* set up the button based on a width of 150px and 100px height */
ul li, ul li a{

    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-position:0 0;
}

ul li{

    float:left;
}

/* roll over - move the background image by the height of the button (100px) */
ul li a:hover{ background-position:0 -100px; }

/* active state - move the background image by twice height of the button (200px) */
ul li a.active, ul li a.active:hover{ background-position:0 -200px; }

/* define each button (background image and text position) */
ul li a.dashboard
{
    background-image:url(images/dashboard.png); /* define image url */
    padding-top:40px; /* position the text using a combination of padding / height) */
    height: 60px;

}
ul li a.products
{
    background-image:url(images/products.png); /* define image url */
    padding-top:30px; /* position the text using a combination of padding / height) */
    height: 70px;

}
...
```

And then I would have the html quite simply:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="dashboard.html" class="dashboard active">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html" class="products">Products &amp; Services</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I haven't actually tested the code but that is my general approach to most html/css based navigation whether it is vertical or horizontal (although I would use 1 large image for all rollover states for all buttons).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to follow it but, before I do, let me ask something about the text position: That text will vary in length, because we will allow several language translations. By taking this into consideration, how will the padding and margin work on this case ?

Comment: Question number 2: :) You said that: "although I would use 1 large image for all rollover states for all buttons" - how will that work if the user chooses to have a bigger font size on is/her browser ?

Comment: Hmmm well it's a bit more tricky then. If you need dynamic text then I guess that would affect the position of the image as well?  If that is the case then I would not have the images as background images as you can't move that according to text size/length....

Comment: The images will always be on center regarding an equal width defined. Only the text should change, so we need to make use of text-align center somehow... I will try something out here and let you know if I found something usefull. :)

Comment: We use an empty span for images but, despite from that, should work pretty well. The fact we use one or several images is really a no issue here, since both should work equally with fluid floated layouts. http://jsfiddle.net/bbjYC/ - I started this css, but most of the credits for this solution should go to Paul O'B.

Comment: Hey have been AWOL since new year, how are you getting on with this, will be able to have a proper look tomorrow?